# Disable TLS 1.3 over TCP

Tags: ssl, tcp, iis, tls

After you create a website in **Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager**, in the config file in the path below,

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

You can modify the following value like this in the specific website section,

```
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:" sslFlags = "32" />
```

What this does is checks the checkbox called `Disable TLS 1.3 over TCP` in `Bindings`. Although this change in the config file checks the checkbox, it does not apply the settings because the website isn't loading. However, if you manually check the `Disable TLS 1.3 over TCP`checkbox, then it works. What is the issue here?

I am going to create a website using an installer to automate the process. But, in Windows Server 2022, it is not loading the website unless `Disable TLS 1.3 over TCP`checkbox is checked.

So, I am looking ways to check `Disable TLS 1.3 over TCP`checkbox using code. But, I need to know why just changing in the config file did not work. I even restarted the website.

Comment: You should figure out why you can't have TLS 1.3 enabled. TLS 1.0 and 1.1 have already been deprecated, and TLS 1.2 will be deprecated in the next few years. You're just delaying the problem.

Comment: Also: https://www.vertexcybersecurity.com.au/tls1-2-end-of-life/

Comment: The website is working fine in Windows Servers 2016 and 2019. But in 2022, it only works if TLS 1.3 is disabled.

Comment: So again, you should try to find out why the website doesn't work with TLS 1.3 enabled on Windows server 2022.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the sslFlags attribute you noticed, it appears IIS also sets a registry key when checking that box:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo\0.0.0.0:443]
"DefaultFlags"=dword:00000040
```

If your SSL binding uses a different port number, you will need to adjust the registry key to match. I also needed to reboot Windows before IIS seemed to notice the registry key change.

Regarding LPChip's comments, I needed to disable TLS 1.3, because my application uses client certificate authentication, and Chrome based browsers do not support post-handshake authentication.